# Android Studio 2.1.2 Build Tools Package not available for download

Tags: android-studio

I'm currently working on an Androir app as part of a group-project for college.
After checking the project out from GitHub I got the following error:
"Error:failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.0 rc3
Install Build Tools 24.0.0 rc3 and sync project"

When I try to install this version of the build tools however, I get this error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XW4uP.jpg)

I tried every solution I can think of (although thats not a lot) but I don't know how to fix this.
I hope someone of you can help me.

Flo

Comment: Change your `build.gradle` and use version 24.0.0

Comment: Doesn't that affect the other group members, when I push these changes back?

Comment: Keep the change locally if others do not want it